# How does MapRoute access the field names of an anonymous type?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How does the implementation of MapRoute connect the `{id}` in the second parameter to `id =` in the third?

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
    );
```

Is it as simple as reflecting on the passed in object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

It creates a [`RouteValueDictionary` instance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routevaluedictionary.aspx) from the `defaults` parameter, which populates itself from the object's `PropertyDescriptor`s.

You can see this in the source:

```
if (values != null) { 
    PropertyDescriptorCollection props = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(values);
    foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in props) { 
        object val = prop.GetValue(values);
        Add(prop.Name, val);
    }
}
```

Comment: where did you get the source, reflector? I was interested to see the code that did the actual reflection- is TypeDescripter it?

Comment: I got that from the reference source for .Net 4.  http://referencesource.microsoft.com/

Comment: `TypeDescriptor` is a standard library in `System.dll`.  By default, it uses reflection, but it can do other things via `ITypedList` and `ICustomTypeDescriptor`.  (That's [how binding to DataTables works](http://blog.slaks.net/2011/01/binding-to-lists-of-datarows.html))